# How can I block email accounts from receiving mail in Parallels Plesk?

Tags: email, plesk, forward

I have a catch all email email@domain.com but wish to deny emails to certain addresses that get bombarded with spam. In CPanel I could set up a the email and then forward to ":fail: No such person at this address" however with Plesk 11 this doesn't seem possible.

Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In plesk on domain level you can set up bounce with some custom message for mail which sent to nonexistent users or setup forwarding to some mailbox, setup autoreply and spam filter on this mailbox.